# Чтение xml файла на "C"

Tags: xml, c

Допустим, есть простой файл xml:

```
<book>
 <title>Introduction to Algorithms</title>
 <edition>Second</edition>
 <authors>
   <author>Thomas H. Cormen</author>
   <author>Clifford Stein</author>
 </authors>
</book>
```

Как мне получить значение поля `<edition>` и, допустим, второго `<author> используя "C" и libxml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте разработчиков `libxml2` есть очень много [примеров](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html) использования ихнего продукта.

Comment: Я не могу найти там exampl-ов, там одни заголовки функций. Можешь дать явную ссылку на пример, как поле вытаскивают?

Comment: Вопрос снят, спасибо, слегка сглупил.